# Html Utility Pack not reading non-ASCII text correctly

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

When I parse a html document instead of getting Japanese text I get something like:

> �͂��߂܂��āB���̓C�t�T�[���ł��A21�΂ł��A�����b�R�ɂ���ł��܂��A���͓��{�̕��������������A�N�������ɓ��{�������邱�Ƃ��ł��܂����A����3�N�ԓ��{���׋����܂����A���̓t�����X���p���A���r�A�������邱�Ƃɂ��������������邱�Ƃł��傤
>   ^*^���͓��{�l�̗F�B�ɉ�����A���������ɂ��闝�R�ł��A�ł́A�܂��B�C�t�T�[��
>   (^*^)\r\n\t\t\t

The encoding in HtmlDocument is set to iso-2022-jp, which seems correct.  I also tried

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to parse, and print this output?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta -     HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);string text = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(932);
doc = web.Load(url);
```

I looked at the Encoding property of the HtmlDocument after it was loaded to find code page 932.  Even though it was detected it wasn't used during the initial read.  UTF8 wasn't the right encoding.